# Erro ao conectar no SQLServer usando JAVA JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Estou usando a lib do sqlserver e minha classe de conexão esta aqui em baixo:

```
public class conexao{

//sqlsever
private static final String USUARIO2 = "usuario";
private static final String SENHA2   = "senha";
private static final String URL2     = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://servidor:1433,usuario,senha";
private static final String DRIVER2  = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc"; //  JDBC driver


public void ConexaoAbrir(){
    try {  
        Class.forName(DRIVER2);

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL2, USUARIO2, SENHA2);     
    } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
    } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
    }
}

}
```

Erro da classe:

[image: bug]

Comment: Você adicionou o jar com o driver do sqlserver no classpath do projeto?

Comment: sim....é sqljdbc.jar na verão 3.0 para conectar ao sqlserver 2000

Comment: Remova isso `Class.forName(DRIVER2);` não é mais necessario no java6.

Comment: Você está tratando "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc" como se fosse uma classe, mas este é o nome do package. O nome da classe é `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`.

Comment: Agora o erro é No suite driver found for  jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://servidor:1433, usuario, senha

Comment: A identificação do "sub protocolo" na string de conexão, "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://", está errada. O correto é `jdbc:sqlserver://`.

Comment: Outra coisa: o separador de propriedades na string de conexão é ponto-e-vírgula (você está usando vírgula). E nunca vi isso de informar apenas os valores - informe também o nome das propriedades, assim: `user=usuario;password=senha;`. Procure por um exemplo de string de conexão no google.

Comment: Como o colega @Caffé disse, o separador está incorreto, se usa `;` para separar url de conexao, usuario e senha.